# Ansible fetch host IP from another group based on defined variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to fetch IP of a host from another group in `inventory` file based on variable name.

Example inventory file:

```
[master]
master-0.example.io
master-1.example.io
master-2.example.io

[replica]
replica-0.example.io master_host=master-0.example.io
replica-1.example.io master_host=master-1.example.io
replica-2.example.io master_host=master-2.example.io
```

Later in playbook I want to run a command, but for that one I require IP of master (FQDN does not work). I have tried following, but this is not working:

```
- name: Test run
  shell: "echo {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}:{{ port }} {{ hostvars['master_host']['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address'] }}:{{ port }}"
```

Any idea if there is a way to get this covered? Or if there is any other way to do this - basically what I need is to match `master-0` with `replica-0` etc. and I do not want to put IPs into `inventory` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hostvars` is a hash. Each top entry in the hash is the name of your host in the inventory. To address that hash, your are using the string `'master_host'` which does not exist. What you want, is to use the value of the variable `master_host` for the particular host your are executing the command on.

The 2 possible correct syntaxes are:

- `{{ hostvars[master_host].ansbible_default_ipv4.address }}`
- `{{ hostvars[master_host]['ansbible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}`

... or any mix between the dot or bracket syntax.

Comment: Hello, thank you for prompt reponse. It did the trick, thank you! I was also trying `hostvars['master_host']['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']`, but it seems that `ansible_default_ipv4` and `address` need to be separated (I am using this kind of syntax in `map` in other part of playbook

Comment: Glad I could help. Read the doc. Map with attribute is expecting a list of subsequent element in order in a hash. Addressing a hash in a jinja2 expression has nothing to do with that.